# Calculate Percent of Total after group_by and count() have been applied to variable

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate percent total for a grouped variable. I have a dataframe with a smoking variable

```
> df$smoking
  [1] NA         "Previous" "Never"    "Current"  "Never"   
  [6] "Never"    "Never"    "Never"    "Current"  "Current" 
 [11] "Previous" "Never"    "Never"    "Previous" "Never"   
 [16] "Previous" "Previous" "Never"    "Never"    "Never"   
 [21] "Never"    "Never"    "Never"    "Never"    "Previous"
```

I want to group by category, count the category, and calculate the percent of total.  I can get the counts just fine and exclude NAs this way:

```
> df %>% 
+   group_by(smoking) %>%
+   filter(!is.na(smoking)) %>%
+   count() 
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   smoking [3]
  smoking      n
  <chr>    <int>
1 Current     93
2 Never      380
3 Previous   213
>
```

But then I can't get the percent of each.  I've looked at multiple other solutions, but they don't seem to work.  For instance, the most common one I've seen results in this:

```
> df %>% 
+   group_by(smoking) %>%
+   filter(!is.na(smoking)) %>%
+   count() %>% 
+   mutate(percent = 100 * n / sum(n))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   smoking [3]
  smoking      n percent
  <chr>    <int>   <dbl>
1 Current     93     100
2 Never      380     100
3 Previous   213     100
>
```

It seems like the "sum(n)" is not crossing groups.  How do I calculate a sum THROUGH the groups as opposed to within them? Thanks for any help!!

Comment: if you add `ungroup()` after the count then it should work.

Comment: Ugh.  Obviously.  Great solution - THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

Putting this down as an answer for posterity:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(smoking) %>%
  filter(!is.na(smoking)) %>%
  count() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(percent = 100 * n / sum(n))
```

For better or for worse, when you run `count()` it does not ungroup the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
> df[!is.na(smoking),] %>% count (smoking) %>% mutate (percent=n/sum(n)*100)
```

^Try the above